# Does Asymptotic notation is a reflection of derivatives?

Tags: data-structures

Why does:

```
O(3n)=O(2n)=O(n)
```

Whereas their derivatives w.r.t n being 3, 2 and 1 respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asymptotic Notation has no relation with derivatives. It is actually a measure of growth of function w.r.t. size of n. So, it tells us how a function will be changed on changing the value of n. If two functions get changed in same manner on changing n in the same way, we would call them the functions of same order.
 For example,
Let f(n)=3n<sup>2</sup>+n+1 and g(n)=5n<sup>2</sup>+3n+1
If we double the n, both functions will roughly get 4 times of previous value. Hence they both are of order O(n<sup>2</sup>). We removed the constant coefficients(5 and 3) in Big-oh notation, because they are not contributing in telling how function is growing w.r.t. n (In every case, function will get 4 times). However we didn't remove the constant 2(power or exponent of n) because it is contributing in telling how function is growing w.r.t. n(Had we removed that constant and our function would get twice instead of 4 times hence we know it is contributing). 
Formally, we define Big-Oh notation as follows:
See here: [Definition of Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)

> `f(n)=O(g(n)),  if and only if f(n)<=c.g(n) for some c>0 and n>=n0`

Now let me show you how O(3n)=O(2n)=O(n)

**Informal Proof:**
f(n)=2n and g(n)=3n both will grow linearly w.r.t. n. By linearly, I mean that if we double/halve n, the function output will also get doubled/halved. It doesn't matter if we change the coefficient to 2,3, or 1000, it will grow linearly w.r.t n. So, that's why O(n)=O(2n)=O(3n)
Notice that it is not about removing constants, it's about whether these constants contribute in telling about how our function is growing w.r.t. n.
As a counter-example for this, Let's suppose
f(n)=2<sup>n</sup> and
g(n)=2<sup>2n</sup>
We can't remove the 2 in exponent because that 2 is contributing and saying that g(n) will actually change in terms of square w.r.t. how f(n) would change.So,
f(n)=O(2<sup>n</sup>)
while g(n)=O(4<sup>n</sup>)

**Formal Proof:**

> `Suppose n is sufficiently large
>
> if f(n)=O(n), g(n)=O(2n) and h(n)=O(3n) then 
> f(n)<=c1n for some c1>0
> g(n)<=2c2n for some c2>0, let's have c3=2c2 hence g(n)<=c3n or g(n)=O(n) or O(2n)=O(n)
> Similarly h(n)<=3c4n or h(n)=O(n) or O(3n)=O(n)
>
> Hence, O(3n)=O(2n)=O(n)`

**Final Words:**
The key point is just to check how a function is growing. After practicing, you'd have some idea like 
an<sup>p</sup>+bn<sup>p-1</sup>+...+c = O(n<sup>p</sup>)
And many more.
Read [CLRS Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). I don't remember exactly but I think Chapter-3 is dedicated for this concept.